# How can I remove a loss added with add_loss()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

If I make a model and then use `add_loss`:

```
model.add_loss(myLoss1(...))
```

And later would like to use a different loss on the same model, how can I, for example, remove `myLoss1` and replace it with `myLoss2`?

I tried `model.losses.clear()`, but that didn't seem to be effective.  I know I could save the weights to disk, remake the model with the desired loss and reload the weights, but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new model using existing model's configuration and then call `add_loss()` again to set new loss. Same goes for restoring model weights.

```
weights = model.get_weights()

# Instantiate model again to remove old loss
model = model.from_config(model.get_config())
model.set_weights(weights)

# Set new loss
model.add_loss(myLoss2(...))
```

Optionally, you might want to reset the global state before you start training your model with new loss, but it depends on your use case.

```
# For Tensorflow's Keras
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

# For Standalone Keras
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Answer (score 2):

**model.losses** has no effect on the model or graph, it would only return you a temporarily generated list, and **model.losses.clear()** would only empty the list, which will not affect the model.
Above this, you have to recompile the model every time, but it is no need to save weights to disk. You can do it below

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model


x = np.random.rand(100).reshape(100, 1).astype(float)
y = np.array(x > 0.5).reshape(100, 1).astype(float)

input_x = Input(shape=(1,), name='input')
d1 = Dense(12, name='d11')(input_x)
d1 = Dense(12, name='d12')(d1)
d1 = Dense(1, name='output1')(d1)
label = Input(shape=(1,), name='label')

model = Model(inputs=[input_x, label], outputs=d1)


def loss1(yi, yp):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((yi - yp) ** 2)
    return loss


def loss2(yi, yp):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((yi - yp) ** 2) * 2

    return loss


model.add_loss(loss1(label, d1))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(3e-4)
model.compile(optimizer, loss=None)
model.fit({'input': x, 'label': y}, None, epochs=100)

# reset model
weights = model.get_weights()
model = Model(inputs=[input_x, label], outputs=d1)
model.add_loss(loss2(label, d1))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(3e-4)
model.compile(optimizer, loss=None)
model.set_weights(weights)
model.fit({'input': x, 'label': y}, None, epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the negative back in.

```
# Existing code
model.add_loss(myLoss1(...))

# New code
model.add_loss(-myLoss1(...))
```